# Mac app - icon not showing correctly / corrupted / garbled up

Tags: xcode, macos, icons

I took doubly care of having all the correct resolutions in my Images.xcassets but still my AppIcon is mixed up:

[image]

What could be the reason for this?

These are the files I used:

```
large-icon.png PNG 128x128 128x128+0+0 8-bit sRGB 2.45KB 0.000u 0:00.009
large-icon@2x.png[1] PNG 256x256 256x256+0+0 8-bit sRGB 4.52KB 0.000u 0:00.000
larger-icon.png[2] PNG 256x256 256x256+0+0 8-bit sRGB 4.52KB 0.000u 0:00.000
larger-icon@2x.png[3] PNG 512x512 512x512+0+0 8-bit sRGB 9.23KB 0.000u 0:00.000
largest-icon.png[4] PNG 512x512 512x512+0+0 8-bit sRGB 9.23KB 0.000u 0:00.000
largest-icon@2x.png[5] PNG 1024x1024 1024x1024+0+0 8-bit sRGB 22.3KB 0.000u 0:00.000
medium-icon.png[6] PNG 32x32 32x32+0+0 8-bit sRGB 874B 0.000u 0:00.000
medium-icon@2x.png[7] PNG 64x64 64x64+0+0 8-bit sRGB 1.52KB 0.000u 0:00.000
small-icon.png[8] PNG 16x16 16x16+0+0 8-bit sRGB 480B 0.000u 0:00.000
small-icon@2x.png[9] PNG 32x32 32x32+0+0 8-bit sRGB 874B 0.000u 0:00.009
```

That is the content of the Images.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset/Contents.json file:

```
{
  "images" : [
    {
      "size" : "16x16",
      "idiom" : "mac",
      "filename" : "small-icon.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "16x16",
      "idiom" : "mac",
      "filename" : "small-icon@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "32x32",
      "idiom" : "mac",
      "filename" : "medium-icon.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "32x32",
      "idiom" : "mac",
      "filename" : "medium-icon@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "128x128",
      "idiom" : "mac",
      "filename" : "large-icon.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "128x128",
      "idiom" : "mac",
      "filename" : "large-icon@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "256x256",
      "idiom" : "mac",
      "filename" : "larger-icon.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "256x256",
      "idiom" : "mac",
      "filename" : "larger-icon@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "512x512",
      "idiom" : "mac",
      "filename" : "largest-icon.png",
      "scale" : "1x"
    },
    {
      "size" : "512x512",
      "idiom" : "mac",
      "filename" : "largest-icon@2x.png",
      "scale" : "2x"
    }
  ],
  "info" : {
    "version" : 1,
    "author" : "xcode"
  }
}
```

I would be very grateful for any insights regarding this issue.

Thank you.

Comment: I see this as well, but only on a macbook air, not my macpro (both running 10.9.5).

Comment: Don't know if this will help at all, but I had a similar issue with .png files when using `sorl`, a Python thumbnailing library. It was using .jpeg encoding on .png files, which caused this effect. Don't have an answer for you, but maybe a clue!